# Linux software RAID60: Can I have global hot spare?

Tags: linux, software-raid, raid

As far as I can see Linux has RAID6 and RAID0, but not RAID60. So RAID60 is emulated by creating RAID0 on top of some RAID6s.

It is possible to add a hot spare to each of the RAID6s, but is it possible to add a global hot spare shared by all the RAID6s? If so, how can that be added to existing RAID6s that are currently assembled automatically (no mdadm.conf)?

Comment: for what it's worth, `So RAID60 is emulated by creating RAID0 on top of some RAID6s` - that's exactly what RAID60 is in any controller, they just might abstract it away into being one set-up step, rather than two.

Answer (score 2):

From http://www.kernelhardware.org/linux-add-share-hot-spare-device-software-raid/

1. Use `mdadm` to hot add the new drive partition to the RAID Array
2. Configure `mdadm.conf` to include `spare-group` setting
3. Configure `mdadm` to run in daemon mode and monitor RAID Arrays

See the linked article for more in-depth details.

Comment: As mentioned: I do not have mdadm.conf. Adapt your answer, so either mdadm.conf is generated automatically or is unneeded.

Comment: try 

mdadm --examine --scan > /etc/mdadm.conf

to generate a fresh mdadm